Geometric measure theory: Notation for the cone of a current
Does anyone know how to type the symbol between 0 and T below ? It comes from the book of Leon Simon geometric measure theory page 157, where he defines the cone over a current. It like a double $x$ or something like that. Thanks in advanced


Does this question help you?

Is it a relation or operation symbol?

It looks simply like two stacked \times
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@foo\relax}} % or \mathbin? or nothing?
\newcommand*{\@foo}[2]{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{\m@th$#1\times$}%
   \ooalign{\raise.25\ht\z@\copy\z@\cr\box\z@}% the .25 might depend on the used font
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$0 \foo T$
$\scriptstyle 0 \foo T$
$\scriptscriptstyle 0 \foo T$

\end{document}


The spacing shown in the figure you post is without \mathrel. I am not sure about the intended use.

Nice, but there's a bounding box problem. With \ooalign the height is taken from the first row and the depth from the second one, so you should reverse the objects. I'd also use \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\times$} rather than \setbox.

I see the issue with the bounding box, but what is the advantage of \sbox in this case?

It's generally best to: \setbox<n>=\hbox{...} hasn't the full protections that are better done with LaTeX. You may get surprises when color is involved. And it's easier to type.
